# Linux on chromeos encountering many errors:58:51

Tags: linux, chrome-book, chrome-os, lxd

OK This is a complex maze of error messages so bear with me.

When I try to open or doing anything with Linux I get

```
[=======/  ] Starting the Linux container Error starting penguin container: 58
Launching VM shell failed: Error starting crostini for terminal: 58
```

When I close and reopen the terminal I get a ready message, then an error message that I can't read because it closes directly after it displays.

This is what I get when I run `lxc list`:

```
(termina) chronos@localhost ~ $ lxc list
+---------+---------+-----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
|  NAME   |  STATE  |         IPV4          | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| penguin | RUNNING | 100.115.92.197 (eth0) |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
(termina) chronos@localhost ~ $
```

I get this when I run `vmc list`:

```
crosh> vmc list
penquin (6238208 bytes, raw, sparse)
termina (5690859520 bytes, min shrinkable size 5021630464 bytes, raw)
Total Size (bytes): 5697097728
```

This happened like one week ago and I ended up powerwash my Chromebook then it worked until now. I really don't what to powerwash it again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: ok now I am getting

```
[====-     ] Starting the container manager Error starting penguin container: 51
Launching vmshell failed: Error starting crostini for terminal: 51
```

I don't know what to do!!!

Comment: Ask where Chrome OS is on topic, that is what you should do. They have better answers because they know the software better: https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/79159593

Comment: OK, thanks. I need 15 characters.